Show $\frac{d}{dx} a^x$ using a log base other than $e$
It can be shown that $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \ln(a)$ using the chain rule by substituting $a = e^{\ln(a)}$. Let's try a different substitution for a, e.g. $a = 10^{\log_{10}(a)}$.
Update:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}10^{\log_{10}(a)x} &= \frac{d}{dx}10^{x\log_{10}(a)} 
\\&= \log_{10}(a)\cdot{(10^x)^{\log_{10}(a)-1}}\cdot10^x\ln(10)
\\&= \log_{10}(a) \cdot {(10^x)^{\log_{10}(a)}}\cdot\ln(10)
\\&= \frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(10)} \cdot (10^{\log_{10}(a)})^x\cdot\ln(10) 
\\&= \ln(a)\cdot a^x 
\\&= a^x\ln(a)
\end{align}$$

How did you arrive at the derivative $a^x \log_{10}(a)$?

Also, please enclose all formulas in dollar signs, like this: $ a^x $. It makes the math render correctly.

Apply chain rule carefully on $10^{xlog_{10}a}$.

The derivative of $t\mapsto10^t$ is $\dots$?

For simplicity, as $\log_{10}(a)$ is a constant, consider it as $kx$. Now carefully differentiate $10^{kx}$

Just a remark: you cannon prove a derivative, you can prove a statement, a theorem, a claim...

As this post is now, there is no question here. What is the question?
I have not reviewed all the edits to the post, but if you post something, and people think about it and answer, and then you edit the post and substantially change what the post says, you have wasted those people's time. And if they went so far as to post their response, then you've made their response irrelevant or nonsensical. Please keep all this in mind if you choose to edit your post.

We have that

$a^x=10^{x\log_{10}a}$
by chain rule: $\frac d{dx}f\left((g(x)\right)=f'\left((g(x)\right)g'(x) \implies \frac d{dx}10^{g(x)}=\left(10^{g(x)} \ln 10\right)g'(x)$

then we obtain
$$\frac d{dx}\left(10^{\left(x\log_{10}a\right)}\right)=\left(10^{\left(x\log_{10}a\right)}\ln 10\right)\left(x\log_{10}a\right)'=\left(a^x \ln 10\right)\log_{10}a=a^x\ln a$$

Your updated solution looks fine with the difference you are using, maybe in a more complicated way, that by chain rule for $f(x)=\left(g(x)\right)^m$
$$\frac d{dx}\left(g(x)\right)^m=m\left(g(x)\right)^{m-1}g'(x)$$

$(())^{−1}′()$

@GeraG Good catch! I fix that, thanks! ;)

Your edit is still wrong. You require a proper understanding of chain rule.
$$\frac{d(10^{kx})}{dx}=\frac{d(10^{kx})}{d(kx)}×\frac{d(kx)}{d(x)}$$
For more simplicity you can consider $kx=u$ and substitute after solving.
Hint for manipulating $k$
$$\log_{10}a=\frac{\ln a}{\ln 10}$$

Your derivation of $\frac{\mathrm d a^x}{\mathrm d x}$ requires using $\frac{\mathrm d 10^x}{\mathrm dx} = 10^x\ln(x)$.
But that's exactly what you are trying to demonstrate!

The reason we use the base as $\mathrm e$, is that it is its definition that leads to the useful property.
$$\begin{align}\mathrm e^x &\!:= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^n\\[3ex]\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathrm e^x}{\mathrm d x~}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^{n-1}\left(\dfrac 1n\right)\\&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^{n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^{-1}\\[1ex]&=\mathrm e^x\\[3ex]\dfrac{\mathrm d a^x}{\mathrm dx}&=\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathrm e^{x\ln a}}{\mathrm d x}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathrm e^y}{\mathrm d y}\!(x\ln a)\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d x\ln a}{\mathrm d x}\\[1ex]&=\mathrm e^{x\ln a}\cdot\ln a\\[1ex]&=a^x\ln a\end{align}$$
$\blacksquare$
